# Two columns don't fit in container with vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a two column layout which has stopped working while tweaking to get rid of the double scroll bars on body. Now I have one scroll bar on wrap which is what I wanted but the contents somehow overlap by the width of the scroll bar.

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font: 12px Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #1e1f21;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: #fff url(../esimages/cubes.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
}

#wrap {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1f21;
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
}

#header {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1f21;
  margin:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

#content1 {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
  margin: 0
}

#content2 {
  float: right;
  width: 290px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
  margin: 0
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #1e1f21;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200%;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

The two content boxes don't fit in the container side by side as they should. I have tried with different reduced fixed widths for content1 but it makes no difference at all and the column width stays the same no matter what. I am tearing my hair out because it's just not logical!

```
<body>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content2">
        <div class="box0">
          <ul>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content1">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div> 

<div id="footer" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a width and `float: left` on `content1`. Also keep in mind that the total width + padding cannot exceed the container's width.

Also, you're missing a semicolon after `margin: 0` for `content1`

Comment: Semicolon was my typo. It is there in my css.
I did have float:left and a fixed width on content1 but read somewhere that it was best to eliminate them both so it would adjust itself to the width available. Anyway it makes no difference.

Comment: Have gone back to having a scrollbar on html rather than on wrap and problem solved.  But if anyone knows how to put a scrollbar just on wrap or container instead without affecting its width, I'd love you to tell me how to do this. Thanks.